# How to find the matrix of an endomorphism in a cyclic basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis, characteristic-polynomial

I am just here to understand a basic concept of linear algebra.

Let be v an endomorphism and its matrix in the canonical basis is given by $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&5&6&3 \\ 1&3&4&5\\4&3&7&8 \\ 1&7&4&3 \end{pmatrix}$, which is just an example (I'm not going to do the calculus because this is not important here). So, it's not difficult to find a characteristic polynomial and another basis $B = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$, in which I can triangulate A.

But now, I have another basis, which is cyclic. Let's call it $B' = (w,v(w),v^2(w),v^3(w))$, with $w = v_1 + v_3$. Again, this is not complicated to do.

However, how do I find the matrix of v in this particular basis using the characteristic polynomial?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You already know how the transformation $v$ acts on the first three basis vectors, $w,v(w),v^2(w)$, in terms of the basis $B'$.  So the only work required involves finding how $v$ acts on the last basis element, $v^3(w)$.  Indeed the characteristic polynomial tells us how to find that., although you can work it out using linear algebra.

Comment: @hardmath So, we have the matrix of the cyclic endomorphism that is $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&-a_0 \\ 1&0&0&-a_1\\0&1&0&-a_2\\0&0&1&-a_3 \end{pmatrix}$ with {$a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$} being the characteristic polynomial coefficients. Right?

Comment: Perfect!  (Assuming we have the characteristic polynomial in its usual monic form.)  What you wrote is called a *companion matrix* for that polynomial.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!